# Add 'Last Modified' and Attachments (Yes/No) to WordPress Users Column

Tags: admin, wp-admin

I was wondering if someone can put me on the right path in regards to adding additional columns that show the last modified date and if a user profile has attachments. Ideally I'd also like to be able to sort these columns.

I'm assuming this is possible, but I'm not quite sure where to start.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Also, just in case this is important - the attachment fields already exist. The last modified field does not.

Comment: It would be useful if you post how you added the attachment fields, since there is no such concept for WordPress users. Have a look at the [`manage_users_columns`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_users_columns) filter to add the column heading and to the [`manage_users_custom_column`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_users_custom_column/) action to manage its content.

Comment: The attachment fields were added with the following plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/